# Windows 2008 R2 RDS - Double Login

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, single-sign-on

Issue:
Double logins when connecting to RemoteApps or Remote Desktop

Environment: 
Gateway = 1 server 2008 R2 - Roles = Gateway, Session Broker, Connection Mgr, Session Host Configuration server

Session hosts = 2 servers 2008 R2 - Roles = App Manager and Session host configuration

Testing:
I can get to the url http://RDS.domain.com/rdweb - I get prompted for authentication (1) Pass authentication, get list of remote apps. Click on remoteapps or remote desktop, get prompted for authentication again (2). Pass authentication, I get access to app or RDP.

Done so far.

- On session host Signed rdp files with cert.
- Added the following to the custom RDP settings:

`Authenticaton level:i:0` = If server authentication fails, connect to the computer without warning (Connect and don’t warn me).

`prompt for credentials on client:i:1` = RDC will prompt for credentials when connecting to a server that does not support server authentication.

`enablecredsspsupport:i:1` = RDP will use CredSSP, if the operating system supports CredSSP.

- Edited the javascript file as found in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977507
- Added Connection ID, and added Web Access server to TS Web Access Computers group on the Session host servers, and Signed apps as found in hxxp://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/08/11/introducing-web-single-sign-on-for-remoteapp-and-desktop-connections.aspx

Note: This double login happens internally and externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this straightened out.. On the Session Hosts.. In Remote Desktop Configuration... RDP-TCP Properties...  Log on Settings Tab...  I did not have selected "Use client-provided log on information"

Once I selected that, on each of the session hosts in the farm. no more double login

Hope this helps someone else out